# jQuery: How to get $(body)[0].scrollHeight with dynamic content?

Tags: jquery

```js
$("#toggle").click(function() {
    $("p").toggle(function() {
        // $('body')[0].scrollHeight <-- this is it, but not in my case
    });
});
```

```html
<a id="toggle">Toggle</a>

<p>content</p>
<p>...</p>
...a hundred more <p>'s that enough to make the scrollbar appear...
<p>...</p>
```

I'm trying to get the scrollHeight when the page content is dynamically changed.

The reason I don't want to use the method in the comment line is because I have other events depending on this dynamic scrollHeight, and I don't really want to write the same thing on every single click.

I'm looking for something like

```js
$('window').scrollHeightChanged(function() {
    // do this
    // do that
});
```

but not

```js
setInterval(function() {
    // check scrollHeight
}, 10);
```

by the way, I'v tried $('#wrapper').resize(), it only works in IE

## UPDATE

I found myself a solution: the jQuery resize event plugin, which made resize() work on all elements. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but at least it detects element size change. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You can basically find the scrollheight whenever you show/hide any content on the page or add any dynamic content on the page to any container. There is not event which will say the content changed on the page.

Also you should find the scrollheight only when the animation complete in case you are using any.